# JQuery selector by custom attribute value and element type

Tags: jquery

I need to select the element by custom attribute value where the element type should be image. 
I know the following selectors to get the element

By element type

```
var imgElms = $("input[type=image]");
```

By custom attribute

```
var cusElms = $("input[myAttr='org']");
```

I need mix of both selector to get all image element that has custom attribute myAttr='org'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'd mix them by simply using both, like this

```
$("input[type=image][myAttr='org']")
```

but note that `myAttr` is not a valid attribute, and you should be using data-attributes instead

Comment: Thanks @adeneo, can you please explain how do I use data attribute? Is this predefined attribute with element, actually I have added two three attributes with  some element for different purpose.

Comment: You just do `<div data-myAttr="org">` instead, and same in the selector `$("input[type=image][data-myAttr='org']")` and it's a valid attribute